# How to create table with runtime data addition - Android

Tags: android, performance, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

I want to create a table in my android application, in which the data will be added on the run time i.e. no. of columns and rows would be decided on the base of user input and user can later add more columns or rows in the Table.

So, using Table Layout of Android is not solving my purpose so far. And I created the table using Linear Layouts under other linear layout, but as I add any row or column I have to create the whole view again which is making the application very slow. So, what can be other approaches or how can I improve the functionality of my application.

Thanks in Adavance.